# What is the relevance of a !Q in the D Flip-Flop when using for a memory module?

Tags: flipflop, memory, latch

[image]

If the purpose of this circuit is to store the value of D in Q, why should I need a !Q? Why don't use a circuit like this instead?:

[image]

Comment: The first diagram is a flipflop.  The second one isn't.  It's a latch.  You can see in the diagram for the flipflop why you need !Q.  It's output feeds back into the circuit.

Comment: @scorpdaddy: The first circuit is a latch, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantages of the first circuit over the second:

- 5 gates instead of 6.
- two gate types (1- and 2-input NAND) instead of three.
- gates that invert (NAND, NOR) are inherently simpler and faster than gates that don't (AND, OR).<sup>1</sup>
- only 2 or 3 levels of gate delay between input and output instead of 3 or 4.

As you can see, there's no disadvantage associated with having the !Q output even if you don't use it.

---

In real SRAM chips, the transistors are made as small as possible in order to pack as many as possible into a given area. In order to maximize the reliability (internal signal to noise ratio), each cell is connected to a pair of complementary bit lines (effectively both Q and !Q), and a differential amplifier is used to sense the state of the selected bit.

---

<sup>1</sup> For details, see [Why are NAND gates used to make AND gates in computers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/394890/11683)

Comment: That NAND and NOR gates are simpler and faster than AND and OR I really didn't know. I think that this is the answer I was looking for. I thought that NAND and NOR gates were both made from AND and OR, but this comes from a Computer Science perspective, not Electrical Engineering, which is the real practice. Thanks man!

Comment: I added a link to a question that explores the details of that.

Answer (score -1):

Logic gates are internally structured in mosfets or transistors, both the OR and AND gates use more mosfets than a NAND gate, as such it ends up as a simpler circuit at that level,

I recommend you follow the image source link as it draws out the internals of the logic gates for you.

[image]

[Image link and a good resource](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/cmos-gate-circuitry/)

Comment: What does this have to do with whether a latch needs a !Q output?